# How to do this Regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to do this for quite some time but for some reason never got it right.

There will be texts like these:

- 12325 NHGKF
- 34523 KGJ
- 29302 MMKSEIE
- 49504EFDF

The rule is there will be **EXACTLY 5 digit number** (no more or less) after that a **1 SPACE** (or no space at all) and some text after as shown above. I would like to have a MATCH using a regex pattern and extract **THE NUMBER and SPACE and THE TEXT**.

Is this possible? Thank you very much!

Comment: try this, \d{5}\s{1}\w+. I suggest you to download Expresso! Good program to learn Regex

Comment: Do you know `Regex`? Please post code you've tried so far.

Comment: @Eray So you want to remove space and get text and number right?

Comment: @Eray, use pattern to find string. after that just extract number and text. int num = int.Parse(text.Substring(0,5)); string text = text.Substring(5);

Comment: THank you but I already tried that, that works but the system I can be only worked with regex patterns..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since from your wording you seem to need to be able to get each component part of the input text on a successful match, then here's one that'll give you named groups `number`, `space` and `text` so you can get them easily if the regex matches:

```
(?<number>\d{5})(?<space>\s?)(?<text>\w+)
```

On the returned `Match`, if `Success==true` then you can do:

```
string number = match.Groups["number"].Value;
string text = match.Groups["text"].Value;
bool hadSpace = match.Groups["space"] != null;
```

Comment: Wow. I had no idea you could do such groups.. I was only extracting single lines which was nothing before you and these people in this post help me..

Answer (score 1):

The expression is relatively simple:

```
^([0-9]{5}) ?([A-Z]+)$
```

That is, 5 digits, an optional space, and one or more upper-case letter. The anchors at both ends ensure that the entire input is matched.

The parentheses around the digits pattern and the letters pattern designate *capturing groups* one and two. Access them to get the number and the word.

Comment: Can we not use Regex.Split in c# for this purpose?

Comment: @freebird Splitting is more forgiving, you could accept inputs that you did not intend to accept.

Comment: Thank you! ... I was using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial article to understand it and its a very good article no-doubt but I wasnt able to put things together properly..

Answer (score 1):

```
string test = "12345 SOMETEXT";
string[] result = Regex.Split(test, @"(\d{5})\s*(\w+)");
```

Comment: Thank you. Andras' answer is similiar to yours. The expression \s* was my problem and now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) method:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var values = new[] 
        { 
            "12325 NHGKF", 
            "34523 KGJ", 
            "29302 MMKSEIE", 
            "49504EFDF" 
        };
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            var tokens = Regex.Split(value, @"(\d{5})\s*(\w+)");
            Console.WriteLine("key: {0}, value: {1}", tokens[1], tokens[2]);
        }
    }
}
```